# Show list of unknown type in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I was given an assignment in which I should have the type signature

```
Group g => Int -> Int -> [[g]]
```

However if g is ambiguous how can I `print` it? I get this error:

```
No instance for (Show g0) arising from a use of ‘print’
The type variable ‘g0’ is ambiguous
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance Show Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
  ...plus 24 others
In the expression: print
In the expression: print $ myTest 10 0
In an equation for ‘main’: main = print $ myTest 10 0
```

Which makes sense to me. Is there an error in the assignment? Or is there a way to `print` an ambiguous type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running

```
> :info Group
```

This should print out the `Group` typeclass and its members, followed by a list of instances.  Pick one of these instances, then execute

```
> myTest 1 2 :: [[TheTypeYouPicked]]
```

If you wanted to use it inside `main` you'll have to give it a type signature there too:

```
main :: IO ()
main = print (myTest 10 0 :: [[TheTypeYouPicked]])
```

The reason why the compiler is showing you this error is because there could be many instances of `Group` to choose from, not all of them necessarily implement `Show` as well.  In order to print something in the console, either by just executing it (there's an implicit `print` when you just run a normal function in GHCi) or with an explicit `print` it needs to implement `Show`.

Comment: What is `f` in your line `f 1 2 :: [[TheTypeYouPicked]]`?

Comment: @AR7 `f` is your function you've been given, you didn't give it a name in your post, just a type, but it's your `Group g => Int -> Int -> [[g]]` function.

Comment: @AR7 I guess it's named in your type signature as `myTest`, I can edit my answer to reflect that.  To be honest, I didn't read the whole error message because the really important information is all within the first 2 lines.